# Custom resolution on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, resolution, osx-mavericks

The only relevant link I found on the internet is the following: [How do I change my resolution on my Mac to a custom size?](https://superuser.com/questions/368468/how-do-i-change-my-resolution-on-my-mac-to-a-custom-size)

The answer is outdated - "Summary of link: the article links to four tools to use. SwitchResX; not free. SetResX; a menu bar resolution switcher (I tried it on Snow Leopard with a non-Retina display and it offered only the same resolutions as System Preferences). ScreenUtil (scrutil); site now down. ChangeResolution‌​; site now down. –  Rory O'Kane Jan 31 at 5:02"

Not willing to use SwitchResX because it isn't free/is too complex.

Basically, what would solve this is a link to ScreenUtil but the site is down and I can't find a mirror ANYWHERE. Any other solutions are welcome.

Comment: I asked a similar question... Maybe we'll get an answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115327/macbook-pro-retina-13-change-resolution-to-1920x1200-pixels